# How to share computer desktop to HoloLens2？

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-10, hololens

I need to share my desktop on Hololens2 in real time.
All the methods I have found deal with synchronizing the HoloLens2 screen to the PC side, instead of the PC side to HoloLens2. I want to try the Unity plug-in FMETP STREAM, but it doesn't seem to meet my requirements. What should I do to synchronize the PC screen to HoloLens2 in real time?
Please excuse my poor English. I would be grateful if you could answer my question.

Comment: If it's not supported per the docs, it's not supported. What's your use case, _why_ do you want your PC on the HoloLens2?

Comment: Most examples are the other way round because it is quite trivial to display a 3D content onto a flat 2D display. The other way round is a bit tricky because if you don't have any depth you wouldn't be able to properly focus at anything because your 2D display would have 0 distance from the head ... too close to your eyes .. what exactly are you trying?

Answer (score 2):

FMETP STREAM should satisfy this use case, I find this [post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/release-fmetp-stream-all-in-one-gameview-audio-stream-udp-tcp-websockets-html.670270/#post-4672061) the developer replied, this package supports the case desktop Unity app stream the content to the VR headset. I believe it should also work for HoloLens.

Besides, the [MixedReality-WebRTC](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/index.html) release from Microsoft can help you enable real-time audio/video/data communication with a remote peer. It also meets your requirements. You can get it starts with this doc:[Unity library overview](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/unity/unity-integration.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify Hololens Remoting player. It streams desktop app to Hololens in real time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/holographic-remoting-player